# When is Zechariah 14:16 happening?

Tags: eschatology, prophecy, revelation

> Everyone who is left of all the nations that came against Jerusalem will go up year after year to bow down to the King, the LORD of hosts, and to celebrate the feast of Booths. 17 Should any of the families of the earth not go up to Jerusalem to bow down to the King, the LORD of hosts, then there will be no rain for them. 18 And if the family of Egypt does not go up or enter, upon them will fall the plague, with which the LORD strikes the nations that do not go up to celebrate the feast of Booths. 19 This will be the punishment of Egypt and the punishment of all the nations that do not go up to celebrate the feast of Booths. 20 On that day, “Holy to the LORD” will be written on the horses’ bells. The pots in the house of the LORD will be as the basins before the altar. 21 Every pot in Jerusalem and in Judah will be holy to the LORD of hosts. All who come to sacrifice will take them and cook in them. No longer will there be merchants in the house of the LORD of hosts on that day (Zech. 14:16-21, NABRE).

How does this fit into the eschatological timeline?  Obviously many would say during the "millennium," but what about those like Catholics who say the millenium is a symbol for the Christian era.  It can't be the eternal order because there are people having the potential to be punished, and presumably everyone who is saved will live in "Jerusalem" then.  There is also the question of all the Mosaic law stuff that is going on.  It sounds like it is the Gog battle from Rev. 20, especially since in Zechariah 14:6-10 it talks about there not being any more night and a river from Jerusalem which sounds like it is happening right after the battle.  But that makes it sound like this is the beginning of the eternal order.  How would someone who rejects a literal millennium explain this?

Comment: Welcome to SE-C. Due to the wide variety of interpretations of the end times it would be necessary to scope this question and address it to just one view of escatology, otherwise it will receive diverse answers from all quarters. The other alternative is to request an overview of all views of the end-times (which will be a huge task). PLease see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of this a _comparative Christianity_ site.

Comment: @NigelJ  I said it was about those who say the millennium is the Christian age.  I don't know how to make it more specific.

Comment: If I understand you aright, that would be the so-called 'Resumptive' view of Revelation in which the Church Age (the ascension of Christ until his return, upon which, immediately, is Judgment and general resurrection) is seen from seven different aspects, layer upon layer. I would suggest adding to the question a very brief reference to, and description of, that view and request responses in regard to that view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Zec 14:16 is a prophetic description of some expectations during the 1000 year reign of Christ (Rev 20:2-6).
2. "those who are left of the nations" are those who survive the "Wrath of God" (Rev 16), which will be poured out from heaven,to destroy all the wicked and ungodly during the Day of the LORD" (Is 13:6-15, Jer 46:10, Joel 1:15-3:15).
3. The only ones to survive the wrath of God are those having been raptured earlier the same day (1Th 4:17-5:2, 2Th 2:1-2), and given immortal bodies at "The Last Trumpet" (1Cor 15:50-52), which trumpet, Jesus calls the "Great Trumpet" (Mt 24:31) and which people, He calls "His Elect" (Mt 24:31), having been given to The Son (Jn 6:39), after having been chosen from before the foundation of the world (Eph 1:4), to be holy and blameless in His eyes (Eph 1:4), and at some point predestined to be adopted as sons of God (Eph 1:5), with their names eternally written into "The Lamb's Book of Life" from the foundation of the world (Rev 13:8, 17:8). They will also be called "blessed of the Father" when they will inherit a kingdom prepared for them from the foundation of the world (Mt 25:34).
4. The Millennial kingdom takes place in a new heavens and a new earth wherein Righteous (Jesus) dwells (2Pet 3:13), because the present sin-cursed heavens and earth will be burned-up with intense heat (2Pet 2;10-12) on "The Day of the LORD", shortly after the Wrath of God has destroyed all the wicked and ungodly (Is 13:6....).
5. The "Feast of Booths" is a significant reminder that God is now dwelling on earth with "His people" (Rev 21:3).  Those who don't honor the king appropriately will be disciplined until they do, because God disciplines/chastises every son whom He loves and receives (Heb 12:5-6).
6. Zec 14:6-10 is a description of some events during "The Day of the Lord", after the sun has been blackened and the moon turned to blood (Act 2:20, Joel 2;31).  It is a glorious day (Act 2:20) because of the resurrection and Rapture.  It is a terrible day (Joel 2:31), because the "Wrath of God" is poured out from heaven (Rev 16) .  Since the stars also fall (Mt 24:29),there will be no light (Zec 14:6), except at "eventime" (Zec 14:7), when every eye will see Him coming....(Rev 1:7, Mt 24:30).
7. The Gog-Magog battle (Rev 20:8), results after Satan once again deceives the nations. Many details of this event and it aftermath can be found elsewhere (Ezk 38-39).
8. As you said, "It sounds like the beginning of the eternal order", because it is...in complete and glorious detail.

Comment: This is a pretty glorious answer, or would be, if you could show that the interpretations came from someone besides yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the excellent question! I have been impressed with a greatly renewed interest in the Feast of Tabernacles this past year and found many connections to the last days and its ongoing significance.

> Everyone who is left of all the nations that came against Jerusalem **will go up year after year to bow down to the King, the LORD of hosts**, and **to celebrate the feast of Booths.**

Clearly this part will come after the said siege of Jerusalem, which is also alluded to by the Savior in Luke 21:21. Modern Apostles in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints have outlined this theme and its place in latter-day events, frequently speaking of and anticipating the Lord's return on the Mount of Olives:

> And it will come to pass, after that period, when Jesus shall have raised all the righteous from their graves, that he will descend with all the hosts of heaven accompanying him, (1 Thes. 4:16 Rev. 1:7 (JST) D&C 88:98) and will stand upon the Mount of Olives, (Zech. 14:4) and he will go out of Jerusalem, and the Jews will go out to the mount to meet him and will acknowledge him as their Messiah and King; (Zech. 13:9) and then it shall come to pass, that the heathen nations will also more fully recognize him as the true and only God. Then will be fulfilled that which is written in the last chapter of Zechariah, that every nation round about Jerusalem, shall come up from year to year, to worship the King, the Lord of hosts, at Jerusalem, and also to keep the Feast of Tabernacles. (Zech. 14:16) **There will be a great many of those solemn assemblies and feasts that were commanded in ancient times, that will be reestablished in the midst of Israel when they shall return**. **And the Lord Jesus will be there.**
> Orson Pratt, [JD 20:142](https://scriptures.byu.edu/#08c139:t30d52$62361:c08a0e16)

> Zechariah says that when [Jesus] comes and stands his feet on the Mount of Olives, all his Saints will come with him. (Zech. 14:5)
> We have found out the place where Jesus will descend, and we have found out who comes with him. Now we enquire will he remain on the earth after he thus descends? Yes, he will remain on this earth as literally and personally as he went around in ancient times, and taught the people from house to house and synagogue to synagogue. And in that day there shall be one Lord, and his name one. (Zech. 14:9) There will not be any heathen gods, for there will be no heathens; no idolatrous worship, (Zech. 13:2) but one Lord, and his name one. (Zech. 14:9)
> And this water which breaks out from the threshold of the Temple, will not only run eastward (Ezek. 47:1) but westward also, (Zech. 14:8) and there will be a great change in the land there, certain portions rising up, others lowered, rough places made smooth and mountains cast down; (Zech. 14:10) and half the waters of this spring which will burst forth, will go towards the former sea and half to the other sea; (Zech. 14:8) in other words half towards the Dead Sea and half toward the Mediterranean.
> **From that day forward there shall be written upon the bells of the horses and upon the vessels of the house of the Lord—“Holiness to the Lord;”** (Zech. 14:20) and thenceforth all the people who are spared from the nations round about, **will have to go up to Jerusalem year by year to worship the King, the Lord of Hosts.** (Zech. 14:16)
> These are some of the grand events spoken of in this Bible; t**hese are events that the Latter-day Saints believe in, and that so far as it lies in their power, they are trying to fulfill.**
> Orson Pratt, [JD 18:57](https://scriptures.byu.edu/#08c139:t2bf27$62360:c08a0e16)

One of the first things to note about the Feast of Tabernacles or of Booths is that, along with the other feasts of ancient Israel, the Lord commanded that it should always be observed in perpetuity by His people, with no expiry:

> "It shall be a statute for ever in your generations" [Leviticus 23:41](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/lev/23.41?lang=eng)

Nevertheless, the people of Israel did not heed the prophets, and for nearly a thousand years after the days of Joshua until Nehemiah, the ancient feast was disregarded. The exceedingly glad occasion of its restoration is [described in Nehemiah chapter 8](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/neh/8?lang=eng).  We are on the verge of a modern renewal of the ancient feasts as was done anciently by the prophets Nehemiah and Ezra.

Notably the ancient observance commanded by the Lord includes a solemn assembly, a Sabbath at either end, and the reading of the word of God for while the people listened from their booths. The people of Israel under Nehemiah also established the practice of sending each other sweet portions of food to accompany their mirth, seeing as the Lord had seen fit to redeem them and take them out of Egypt and from Babylon after the Days of their Repentance and the Day of Atonement on their behalf were completed.

An overview of the ancient observance of the Feast of Tabernacles can be found here on the Messages of Christ channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6PmxypqZ9I

### Modern Renewal

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints regularly holds a multi-day semiannual General Conference, which happens to align uncannily well with the ancient feasts of Israel (as well as can be expected given that the modern Western world is currently under a Gentile rather than an Israelite calendar), notably with the April General Conference being held close to the Passover, and October General Conference often falling on the Feast of Tabernacles.

There is strong evidence that the ancient American people, [the Nephites, kept the Feast of Tabernacles](https://archive.bookofmormoncentral.org/content/king-benjamin-and-feast-tabernacles), being a remnant of the House of Israel through Joseph, the branches that run over the wall. The General Conferences have been likened to this gathering around the temple, with all the people pitching their tents with the door towards the temple to hear the word of God:

[image: King Benjamin preaching to the people of Nephi]

The central feature of the feast is remembrance of the captivity of our fathers, and the reading of the book of the law of God:

> Also day by day, from the first day unto the last day, he read in the book of the law of God. (Nehemiah 8:18)

Many members of the church, myself included, have noticed the [likeness](https://whatwewantourgrandchildrentoknow.wordpress.com/2023/10/09/the-feast-of-tabernacles/) between the peculiar practice of a semiannual General Conference and the Feast of Tabernacles. Yes, we even celebrate General Conference with [traditional](https://www.deseret.com/2022/9/21/23364007/general-conference-2022-cinnamon-rolls/) [cinnamon rolls](https://dandelionmama.com/2012/10/05/general-conference-cinnamon-rolls-2/), following the pattern of Nehemiah's people.

Although living in booths is not yet explicitly part of the modern observance, the similarities are striking, and it has been envisioned that the broadcasting of the conference to all the world as people listen from their dwellingplaces constitutes a refreshing of the ancient practice; we recognize we are regarded as strangers in whatever land we are in under present-day geopolitics, symbolic of the Exodus from Egypt as the children of Israel dwelt in booths, in the Spirit of the original feast. [All nations are invited today to participate in the General Conference of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference?lang=eng) The Conference includes a [solemn assembly](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2018/04/solemn-assembly?lang=eng).

The Feast of Tabernacles is not the only one renewed and fulfilled in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. The Book of Mormon: Another Testament of Jesus Christ, the book by which the world shall be judged, was revealed [on the very day of the Feast of Trumpets in 1827](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/2000/01/the-golden-plates-and-the-feast-of-trumpets?lang=eng), ushering in our Days of Repentance prior to our Day of Atonement and the Lord's final gathering of His people.

[The Day of Atonement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UYT-0AmlnA) was the only day in the year when the high priest was allowed to enter the Holy of Holies and make atonement for Israel anciently. In modern times, each temple has a Holy of Holies, and only the prophet and president of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (who is a high priest) may enter, and he does so making supplication for the Lord's people.

There is a group in Utah that hosts free public tours of a life-size replica of the ancient tabernacle of Israel:
https://tabernacletour.com/

The leaders of the church today recognize the General Conferences as fulfilling the ancient requirement of the Lord to His people to keep this holy feast:

> As directed, we have assembled “to worship the King, the Lord of hosts” (Zech. 14:16)
> [David B. Haight, 1992](https://scriptures.byu.edu/#08c139:t1483$43089:c08a0e16)

> Should any of the families of the earth not go up to Jerusalem to bow down to the King, the LORD of hosts, then there will be no rain for them. And if the family of Egypt does not go up or enter, upon them will fall the plague, with which the LORD strikes the nations that do not go up to celebrate the feast of Booths. This will be the punishment of Egypt and the punishment of all the nations that do not go up to celebrate the feast of Booths.

This is plainly enough stated, and the commandment to turn from idolatry and worship the Lord is plainly enough elucidated by Apostle Orson Pratt above.

> On that day, “Holy to the LORD” will be written on the horses’ bells.
> The pots in the house of the LORD will be as the basins before the
> altar. Every pot in Jerusalem and in Judah will be holy to the LORD
> of hosts. All who come to sacrifice will take them and cook in them.

There exists a [peculiar people](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/tg/peculiar-people?lang=eng) today who are already bringing this about.

> I am grateful that our temples all bear the words “The House of the Lord, Holiness to the Lord.” This reminder of holy places has roots that go back to the Old Testament. Zechariah reminds us that the day will come when “there [shall] be upon the bells of the horses, HOLINESS UNTO THE LORD. … Yea, every pot in Jerusalem and in Judah shall be holiness unto the Lord of hosts.” (8  Zech. 14:20–21)
> [James E. Faust, 2005](https://scriptures.byu.edu/#08c139:t1bce$44273:c08a0e20c1)

The doorknobs of the Salt Lake Temple of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints contain the writing, "Holiness to the Lord":

[image: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/media-library/images/salt-lake-temple-lds-661115?lang=eng&clang=ase]

It also appears in bold lettering on every temple built by the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints:

[image: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/media-library/images/salt-lake-temple-exterior-789727?lang=eng]

Focus on this inscription is a pervasive theme in all of the doings of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints:

> Zechariah prophesied that in the day of the Lord’s millennial reign, even the bells of the horses would bear the inscription “Holiness unto the Lord.” (Zechariah 14:20) In that spirit, the pioneer Saints in these valleys affixed that reminder, “Holiness to the Lord,” on seemingly common or mundane things as well as those more directly associated with religious practice. It was inscribed on sacrament cups and plates and printed on certificates of ordination of Seventies and on a Relief Society banner. “Holiness to the Lord” also appeared over the display windows of Zion’s Cooperative Mercantile Institution, the ZCMI department store. It was found on the head of a hammer and on a drum. “Holiness to the Lord” was cast on the metal doorknobs of President Brigham Young’s home. These references to holiness in seemingly unusual or unexpected places may seem incongruous, but they suggest just **how pervasive and constant our focus on holiness needs to be**.
> [D. Todd Christofferson, 2017](https://scriptures.byu.edu/#08c139:t204a$133271:c08a0e20)

> No longer will there be merchants in the house of the LORD of hosts on
> that day (Zech. 14:16-21, NABRE).

The word used in the KJV is "[Canaanite](https://www.godrules.net/library/kjvstrongs/kjvstrongszec14.htm)" rather than "merchant". I know of no modern expounding of the meaning of this particular reference.

> How would someone who rejects a literal millennium explain this?

We believe in the literal Millennium, so no help there; I will confine myself to addressing the more general question in the title.